# Django admin Filter Horizontal Widget limitation on number of objects

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Many-to-many relationship in my Django model. On my admin page, I used `filter_horizontal = ["destination_name"]` to display this relationship. As my data grows up if the relationship includes more than 1000 rows for an object, the "filter_horizonal" widget **shows only the first 1000** objects in the relationship. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem on the admin page?

Comment: When there are more than 1000+ rows, are you planning to show all of them?

Comment: Yes. Our P.O. needs such a feature but this widget has a search bar on the top.